# Wordpress Contact Form 7 customize HTML output of shortcodes

Tags: php, html, wordpress, contact-form

I would like to customize the HTML output of a Wordpress Contact Form 7 (WPCF7) shortcode itself, i.e. the `[file]` shortcode. I **do not want to modify the surrounding HTML**.

So far I've modified the HTML output by changing the contents of the file `/contact-from-7/modules/file.php`.

My changes will be lost when I update the plugin. So I'd like to implement a more *permanent* and *robust* solution, like adding a filter in my `functions.php`.

What I would like to do (**pseudo code - untested code**):

```
add_filter('wpcf7_file_shortcode_handler', 'my_file_sc_handler');
function my_file_sc_handler($html) {
    $html = sprintf('<div>my own html</div>');
    return $html;
}
```

I only not need to change the `$html` returned - no need to touch the remaining code of the `wpcf7_file_shortcode_handler` function.

**My question:** How can I customize the Wordpress Contact Form 7 HTML output of the `[file]` shortcode so that my changes will not get lost when I update the plugin?

Comment: I don't think it's exactly clear on what you want to do. When you say `[file]`, am I right in assuming this is for a file upload in part of a form? So I'm guessing you just want to provide a custom file submit button display? You could try adding a class to the shortcode, and styling it that way, if that helps?

Comment: @Lee thank you for your suggestion. You are right, I want to modify the HTML output of the `[file]` shortcode itself. And, unfortunately, just adding a few css styles will not work. I need some extra HTML elements (which I could insert via jQuery, but I want to change the file shortcode HTML output directly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and such, although I do not have a solid answer, I think you may find the answer you're looking for with this link:

http://www.featheredowl.com/contact-form-7-submit-button-element/

This tutorial explains how to manipulate the `[submit]` shortcode from using `<input type="submit">` to a `<button>` element.

Using this basis, you may be able to customise your `[file]` output to how you want.

Although this does require editing core files, it also seems to set about handing upgrades of the plugin through functions.

Hope it helps somewhat!

Comment: Thank you, @Lee. This looks promising. I will give it a try and post my answer to Stackoverflow. The CF7 plugin has received some internal changes since version 3.9 so I guess I'll have to modifiy the code from your linked example a bit... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it is a very bad idea to change the core files of any plugin.

If it is simply the HTML output that you want to change, why don't you change it in the provided editor, see below example:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<p>Name<br />
    [text your-name] </p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<p>Email*<br />
    [email* your-email] </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<p>Enquiry<br />
    [textarea your-message] </p>
<p>[submit "Send"]</p>
</div>
</div>
```

You can pretty much change everything!

Comment: This isn't exactly true, for example the standard [submit] is used as an input type rather than a button. This makes it very difficult to change, if you want to use a button instead of an input. I believe he wants to change the actual output of what `[file]` gives.

Comment: @Siegfried Grimbeek I do not want to change the HTML code **around** the `[file]` shortcode, I want to modify the output **of** the `[file]` shortcode itself.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot insert a contact form shortcode into your template file directly. You will need to pass the code into do_shortcode() function and display its output like this

```
    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="7" title="Contact"]' ); ?>
```